# how can i Pause vue-panZoom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable, panzoom

I have a Grid with [vue-panZoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-panzoom)

inside it there is a [vue-draggable-resizable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-resizable) area like in the image below

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUDeD.png)

When i drag the (vue-draggable-resizable) gray square, the black (pan-zoom) rectangle also moves.
when the gray square is selected, the panZoom must be locked or in the beforeMouseDown & beforeWheel mode state.

```
<panZoom :options="{transformOrigin: null, beforeWheel, beforeMouseDown}">

<vue-draggable-resizable ***@dragging="onDrag"*** ref="draggable" :active="true"  @dragstop="updatePreview" @resizestop="updatePreview">
```

there is also this method in the panzoom documentation but i don't know if it could work in vue too:

> Pause/resume the panzoom You can pause and resume the panzoom by
> calling the following methods:

```
var element = document.getElementById('scene');
var instance = panzoom(element);

instance.isPaused(); //  returns false
instance.pause();    //  Pauses event handling
instance.isPaused(); //  returns true now
instance.resume();   //  Resume panzoom
instance.isPaused(); //  returns false again
```

how can i solve? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those methods should work with Vue.js. All you have to do is access `$panZoomInstance` via ref.

```html
<pan-zoom ref='panZoom'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
</pan-zoom>
```

```js
methods: {
  pause() {
    this.$refs.panZoom.$panZoomInstance.pause()
  },
  resume() {
    this.$refs.panZoom.$panZoomInstance.resume()
  }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/avxs0ec9/)